# VBA: Moving and deleting Excel rows to other worksheet based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently creating a worksheets which moves rows in Excel that contain a cell containing the text "Voltooid" to a second worksheet. I want to either move the rows, or copy+paste and delete them, based on cell value.

Up until now, I've been able to build a function that deletes rows in the table. Please see the code below:

```
Sub DeleteCompleted()
Dim Test1 As ListObject
Dim Test2 As Variant
Dim Rowcount As Integer

Set Test1 = Sheets("To Do Lijst").ListObjects("Table2")
Test2 = Test1.ListRows.Count

For Rowcount = 1 To Test2 Step 1
    If Test1.DataBodyRange(Rowcount, 4) = "Voltooid" Then
    Test1.DataBodyRange(Rowcount, 4).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rowcount = 0
    End If
Next Rowcount
```

Can you suggest a better format for me?

Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: A few comments. When removing elements from a list, of any sort, you should work top to bottom, otherwise you risk missing items. To do so append `Step -1` to your `For`statement. Also setting `rRowcount = 0` within your `For` loop will likely cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using descriptive variable names makes your life easier
2. Always use `Long` for row counting variables, Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Also never use `Variant` unless you really have to.
3. If you delete/add rows you must loop backwards, because deleting/adding changes the row count.
4. To move a row use `Range().Cut` and define a destination, eg next free row in another worksheet.

So you end up with something like …

```
Sub DeleteCompleted()
    Dim ToDoList As ListObject
    Dim ListRowCount As Long
    Dim iRow As Long

    Set ToDoList = Sheets("To Do Lijst").ListObjects("Table2")
    ListRowCount = ToDoList.ListRows.Count

    Dim NextFreeRow As Range

    For iRow = ListRowCount To 1 Step -1
        With ToDoList
            If .DataBodyRange(iRow, 4).Value = "Voltooid" Then
                Set NextFreeRow = Worksheets("Destination").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -3)
                ToDoList.ListRows(iRow).Range.Copy Destination:=NextFreeRow
                ToDoList.ListRows(iRow).Range.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        End With
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't agree with 1. more.

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for the answer. However, upon executing this piece of code, I've seen the rows on my second worksheet actually overwrite each other. No new completed lines are added after the first.

I've also noticed that Column A isn't filled in the second worksheet. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I improved my answer. Copy the whole sub and try again.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Amazing what some people can achieve.

Comment: Final question. I've got this thing working now - it takes 6 cells per row (first 6 columns) and adds it to the worksheet archive. In column 7 (G) I would like to automatically add the date upon which the macro was run. Is there a way to fill the correct cell in column G to reflect the date on which that particular row was filled?

Comment: `NextFreeRow` represents the first cell in the row where the copy is inserted and with `Offset(rows, columns)` you can move. So `NextFreeRow.Offset(0, 6).Value = Date` will write the date into the cell 6 columns right of `NextFreeRow`.